# "gclient sync" fails due to SSL3 certificate verify failed

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate, synchronization, chromium

I have been trying to fetch chromium source code.  However, I got stuck on `gclient sync` for 2 days.
`gclient sync` fails every time due to error related to SSL certificate verification failure.

**LOG is as below:**

```
rna@rna-P580:~/workspace/project$ gclient sync
Syncing projects:  98% (83/84), done.                                                               

________ running 'download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=linux* --no_auth --bucket chromium-gn -s src/buildtools/linux32/gn.sha1' in '/home/rna/workspace/project'
/home/rna/workspace/project/depot_tools/third_party/boto/pyami/config.py:75: UserWarning: Unable to load AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE ()
  warnings.warn('Unable to load AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE (%s)' % full_path)
Failure: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:509: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed.

Error: Command download_from_google_storage --no_resume --platform=linux* --no_auth --bucket chromium-gn -s src/buildtools/linux32/gn.sha1 returned non-zero exit status 1 in /home/rna/workspace/project
```

I am guessing this happens because i am behind company firewall.
So I requested to open http & https. But still no luck.
Can someone help me out, please? I'm on `ubuntu 13.10`

Comment: i installed custom crt file on Ubuntu then it worked

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well, what fixed it for me was doing: `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score -1):

---

I modified DEPS below /trunk directory, comment some code as :

```
#{
#    # Download test resources, i.e. video and audio files from Google Storage.
#    "pattern": "\\.sha1",
#    "action": ["download_from_google_storage",
#               "--directory",
#               "--recursive",
#               "--num_threads=10",
#               "--no_auth",
#               "--bucket", "chromium-webrtc-resources",
#               Var("root_dir") + "/resources"],
#  },
,
```

and retry to run gclient runhooks and I can get a correct result.

FROM:
https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=3314